# How to position an image inside a button?

Tags: html, css, button

İ have this button, and i want to but an image at the left, and it should have a text

which i could position as i want inside the button. i tried a few ways but i couldn't position

the text and image the way i wanted.

```
 <button class ="buttn"> Click Here <img src ="./logo.png"> </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.buttn{
    background:transparent url(/logo.png) no-repeat left;
    border:0;
    padding-left: xxxpx; // this is how wide the image is plus any additional padding
}

<button class="buttn">Click Here</button>
```

The path should be replaced with the correct one.
Basically, set the image as the background, remove any default button styling and then play with the padding until you position the text as expected.

Multiples:

```
.buttn{
    background-image:url(/logo.png), url(/gradient.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat, repeat-x;
    background-position:center left, center left;
}
```

You don't need to use an image for the gradient, by the way. Just showing that you can have more than one background.

Comment: You can also provide multiple backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

Ive never put an image in a button. I'm guessing it doesn't show that. In which case wrap the button in a div with float left (or same demensons as button) and position relative. Position the image with absolute positioning where you want it. Use padding in the button to push the text which ever way you want it to go. If padding doesn't work then wrap the text in span and AP it to.

Kai answer is cleaner if it works in all browsers.